# What approach is best suited for analysing relationship between X_inputs and Y_output?

Tags: input, lstm, product, analysis

A set of restaurants have product mix informations well as Food Cost/Netto % like in the data sample below:

Restaurant 1:
Input: Pizza - 60%, Pasta - 25%, Hamburgers - 10%, Steaks - 5%. Output: Cost - 25% of Netto
Restaurant 2:
Input: Pizza - 45%, Pasta - 45%, Hamburgers - 8%, Steaks - 2%. Output: Cost - 20% of Netto
Restaurant 3:
Input: Pizza - 47%, Pasta - 38%, Hamburgers - 14%, Steaks - 1%. Output: Cost - 27% of Netto

Assuming we have prior knowledge that food cost of Pizza is higher than the rest and the rest have approximately the same food cost per unit. By eyeballing this sample we can see Restaurant 3 has unusually high food cost % as it makes less pizza and should have less cost%.
What is the best analysis approach for such a problem? I've tried multivariate LSTM to predict food cost and then take the difference with actual value to see worst performing restaurants. Results are mixed.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why use Long Short Term Memory neurons ?

You could just use a basic Neural Network with 4 inputs

- Pizza
- Pasta
- Hamburgers
- Steaks

and 1 outputs :

- Cost / Netto%

Don't mind me if I m wrong but 'Cost/Netto%' term is kidda confuse

Comment: Sorry, it means Food Cost to Netto percentage. Meaning what percentage of Net income is Food Cost? I'll look into the NN option. Thanks

Comment: you may need 2 output one for cost and one for Netto%
This give basicly :
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

 tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu' , input_shape=4),

])